# store the value in array and return the function ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

item has array of hash. ex.
item = [{item1},{item2},{item3}]

```
def function1
   item.map( other_class.call )
end

# other class will return the array which contains string
class other_class
   def call 
     #method which return arrray of strings
   end
end
```

currently the function1 is returning the array of array which has string values.

`function1 output example [["str1"], [], ["str2"], ["str3"], ["str4","str5"]]`

I want to modify the function1 which will return the array of string.

```
expected output = ["str1" "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5"]
```

Guys, any idea how can I modify the above method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `flat_map` instead of `map`. BTW, next time please take 5 minutes to write meaningful example code that actually produces such output (instead of adding comments describing what it _should_ do)

Comment: @Stefan thanks for feedback, next time I'll try to add more details as much it needed.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
item=[["str1"], [], ["str2"], ["str3"], ["str4","str5"]]
```

Code

```
p item.flatten
```

output

```
["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5"]
```

So you should write something like

```
def function1
   other_class.call.flatten
end
```

Comment: Shanti, I can't imagine an answer better than `item.flatten` but in general I suggest you wait at least a couple of hours before selecting an answer. The act of selecting an answer may discourage the posting of other answers or even the reporting that the selected answer is incorrect (though the latter does not apply here). There is no rush to make a selection.